# C++ static_cast with assert

Tags: c++

Unfortunately, I have to perform a narrowing cast when calling a 3rd party library. I don't want to impose an overhead in my release build, so will be using a static_cast. However, it's an array index so could lead to some entertainment if it ends up negative. Is there some way to create a safe cast in debug mode only that will check the value to ensure there is no loss during the cast? The only way I can think of is to  use macros, and I'd rather not.

For example, in both release and debug mode using MSVC:

```
int main() {
  long long ll = std::numeric_limits<long>::max();
  ++ll;
  std::cout << ll << "\n";
  long l = static_cast<long>(ll);
  std::cout << l << "\n";
}
```

results in the output:

```
2147483648
-2147483648
```

Using a  macro:

```
template<class to, class from>
to checked_static_cast(const from& from_value) {
  to to_value = static_cast<to>(from_value);
  if (static_cast<from>(to_value) != from_value)
    throw std::runtime_error("Naughty cast");
  return to_value;
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define debug_checked_static_cast(to, val) checked_static_cast<to>(val)
#else
#define debug_checked_static_cast(to, val) static_cast<to>(val)
#endif

int main() {
  try {
    long long ll = std::numeric_limits<long>::max();
    ++ll;
    std::cout << ll << "\n";
    long l = debug_checked_static_cast(long, ll);
    std::cout << l << "\n";
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }
}
```

results in the same output in release mode, but the following in debug:

```
2147483648
ERROR: Naughty cast
```

Any better options?

NB: I'm disregarding the entertainment we might enjoy from an array large enough to cause this issue, and perhaps this is simply over-paranoid, but I imagine the concept may have applications other than my specific requirement.

Comment: Given what you're trying to do, I don't see any problem with doing it exactly the way you did (and I am generally anti-macro). But consider whether you really want to have this check turned off in release mode given that you apparently consider the consequences of failure severe enough to justify throwing an exception in debug mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No macro needed, you can simply use preprocessor conditionals inside the function body:

```
template<class to, class from>
inline to debug_checked_static_cast(const from& from_value) {
  to to_value{static_cast<to>(from_value)};
#if _DEBUG
  from round_trip{to_value};
  if (round_trip != from_value)
    throw std::runtime_error("Naughty cast");
#endif
  return to_value;
}
```

and

```
template<class to, class from>
inline to debug_checked_coercion(const from& from_value) {
  to to_value{from_value};
#if _DEBUG
  from round_trip{to_value};
  if (round_trip != from_value)
    throw std::runtime_error("Naughty cast");
#endif
  return to_value;
}
```

Then use

```
long l = debug_checked_coercion<long>(ll);
```

Notice that I've minimized the use of `static_cast`, since it isn't needed for narrowing numeric conversions.

Comment: The first seems to work well, I like it, but the `debug_checked_coercion` gives me a warning `C4244: 'initializing' : conversion from 'const __int64' to 'long', possible loss of data`. It may be because I'm on MSVC2010?

Comment: @Rai: Just use pragma warning around this one function to locally disable that warning.  The whole purpose of the function is to perform a narrowing conversion.  (Warnings are to bring potential problems to the programmer's attention, and our full attention is on the narrowing conversion here)

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to agree with dlf in that if its important enough to throw an exception in Debug, then you should probably be doing it in Release also.

If I had the choice of efficient code that sometimes crashes, and slightly less efficient code that doesn't I know what I would choose.

Paul.

Comment: But throwing an exception is unlikely to prevent a crash.  Are you perhaps suggesting using the wider type everywhere and not performing a narrowing conversion?